# Unable to run Plone site

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I am using Plone for my site When i am trying to run following command it gets an error :
**Plone/zinstance $ bin/instance fg**

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
File "/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/bin/interpreter", line 297, in <module>
    exec(compile(__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec"))
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>
    run(/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run
    starter.prepare()
  File "/home/turningcloud/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 79, in prepare
    self.setupServers()
  File "/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 214, in setupServers
    % (server.servertype(),e[1]))
ZConfig.ConfigurationError: There was a problem starting a server of type "HTTPServer". This may mean that your user does not have permission to bind to the port which the server is trying to use or the port may already be in use by another application. (Address already in use)
```

Comment: Seems like you are already running some sort of server on the system on the same port.

Comment: But i did not install or using any other server its using only default server i.e. **nginx**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did not change the Plone configuration, it is trying to bind to port 8080. The error message indicates the port is already in use.

The most common reason is that this or another Plone instance is using the port. If you don't have another Plone install, then it may be the current Plone install, with the Plone daemon running as a background process. Try using `bin/instance stop`.

If that doesn't work and this is a development machine that you control, you may wish to simply reboot it. Otherwise, use your operating system's process-monitor mechanisms (`ps aux | grep python` on a Linux system) to find out if Plone is already running. If so, kill the process.

Plone is not the only package that uses 8080 as its default port. If the above has failed, use a network monitor program (netstat or sockstat on a Linux system) to track down the other process listening on the port. Change its configuration or Plone's.

Comment: Also you can head to http://localhost:8080 within your browser to quickly see who's sabotaging you.

Comment: I should use CTRL+C in place of CTRL+D ..that the problem ...well thanks steveM

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo netstat -lnap | grep 8080
```

Check which process is using the port 8080 and use "kill " command to kill it and then again restart it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. I got some hint from this post http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Address-Already-in-Use-error-td328781.html

I went to back to my command and seen that I was using wrong user in command with sudo.

sudo -u plone_daemon bin/instance fg --- Wrong command

sudo -u [Change_user_respectively] bin/instance fg -- It worked for me.

Comment: That's interesting, the post you're linking to talks about restarting via the ZOPE-controlpanel (`[HOST]:[PORT]/Control_Panel/manage_main`), only found a shutdown-button there and after shutting down `netstat` shows several entries for port `8080` with the state `TIME_WAIT`. Tested with a ZEO-install.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your infos! Could it be you initially installed Plone as root and that is the origin of the hassles?

Comment: Yes. Its true. I had installed Plone as root.