# My website doesn't work and cannot start Plone. bin/instance fg doesn't work

Tags: http, webserver, plone

My web server’s power outage occurred and then my webpage doesn’t work anymore. I’m using Plone ver 4.3.3 and Zope.
I found there is no problem at apache2 so i think the problem is at the plone. So I tried to restart plone and there was the problem.
I typed **bin/instance fg** but i got error message like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/kwlee/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/bin/interpreter”, line 265, in 
exec(compile(__file__f.read(), file, “exec”))
File “/home/kwlee/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22- 
py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py”, line 76, in 
run()
File “/home/kwlee/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22- 
py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py”, line 22, in run
starter.prepare()
File “/home/kwlee/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22- 
py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/init.py”, line 79, in prepare
self.setupServers()
File “/home/kwlee/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22- 
py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/init.py”, line 214, in setupServers
% (server.servertype(),e[1]))
ZConfig.ConfigurationError: There was a problem starting a server of type 
“HTTPServer”. This may mean that your user does not have permission to bind to the port which the server is trying to use or the port may already be in use by another application. (Permission denied)
```

So i searched if there is another Plone running, so i did **bin/instance stop** and started again, but that couldn’t solve my problem.
And i did **ps aux | grep python** and the result was like this.

```
root 2974 0.0 0.0 17164 964 pts/14 S+ 16:38 0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: To get started, check whether port is already in use somehow with `netstat -tulpn` or `lsof -i`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run Plone site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218728/unable-to-run-plone-site)

Comment: try `sudo supervisorctl`

Comment: I would try `ps auxwww | grep -i python` or instead of searching for ‘python’ try searching for a string that is part of the path where you installed Plone. Also, please post your questions to our forum where more people will see them, https://community.plone.org (...and I see you did post there and have been getting responses; great!)